# How to create a sequentially ordered list in R with lapply and replicate?

Tags: r

I have been trying to avoid for loops in `R`. However, I have had issues with using `lapply` with `replicate` in that the lists I obtain have ordering that are not sequential. For example, the following code:

```
lapply(1:5, function(x) replicate(100, rnorm(x), simplify = F))
```

creates 100 instances of each: `rnorm(1)`, `rnorm(2)`, ..., `rnorm(5)`.

This is much faster than using a for loop. However, the resulting list indices I get are:

```
.........
[[5]][[98]]
[1] -0.87686000 -0.82373642 -0.05671333 -2.24652788 -1.43497760

[[5]][[99]]
[1] -1.6935926  0.4753606  0.1190997  0.1464246  0.8604974

[[5]][[100]]
[1]  0.68414921  0.32183115  1.23681540 -1.34076190 -0.08467215
```

while what I want is:

```
[[1]] -0.87686000
[[2]] -0.8237
......
[[500]] 1.236
```

Is there a way to modify the code above so that it order the list from 1 to 500? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call `unlist()` on the result, e.g.:

```
unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x) replicate(100, rnorm(x))))
```

Though note that you'll get an atomic vector of length **1500** -- since you're generating 1+2+3+4+5=15 random values 100 times.

That what you're aiming for?

If the goal is to get 500 total values, where the mean changes from 1 to 5 within each iteration, then you can just say:

```
unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x) replicate(100, rnorm(1, mean=x))))
```

You can see the upward trend with, e.g.:

```
values <- unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x) replicate(100, rnorm(1, mean=x))))
plot(seq_along(values), values)
```

[image]